# Spacemacs, using a package not found in melpa

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, package-repositories

I want to use the package `ox-ipynb` in spacemacs.

I tried adding under `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`,  but I guess since it's not on melpa, spacemacs couldn't find it.

I've also tried downloading the ox-ipynb.el file itself and loading it directly in my org-mode buffer like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (load-file "~/emacs/ox-ipynb.el")
#+END_SRC
```

which gave me: `load-with-code-conversion: Symbol’s value as variable is void: Skip`

Any suggestions?
And in general, how do I make spacemacs install packages that are not on melpa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a quelpa recipe under `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` in your dotfile as follows:

```
    (ox-ipynb :location (recipe
                         :fetcher github
                         :repo "jkitchin/ox-ipynb")))
```

Currently, this possibility is only described in [the docs about 'configuration layer development`](https://develop.spacemacs.org/doc/LAYERS.html#packagesel)

Alternatively, you can install my [small update of benneti's spacemacs jupyter layer](https://github.com/dalanicolai/spacemacs-jupyter). I once started that update, but probably I did not consider it finished as I did not push it to github (I guess I just wanted to add some things to the README). But as far as I know it is fully functional (not tested), so I pushed it now.